# driver.mobile.set_network_connection(driver.mobile.AIRPLANE_MODE) giving operation unsupported on Android exception

Tags: python, selenium, mobile, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am executing script using appium with python selenium webdriver. I have a scenario where i need to turn on Airplane mode on real android device. I have used
`driver.mobile.set_network_connection(driver.mobile.AIRPLANE_MODE)` in my script. But it is showing some "Operation is Unsupported on Android" msg.

Is there any alternate method to get the above operation done..?

Details:

Driver: Webdriver
Appium: 1.4.16.
Device OS: 4.4.4
Scripting in Python.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Found a solution, executed the airplane mode cmd using adb.

Answer (score 0):

We did this by automating the steps to enable airplane mode i.e writing code to open menu and clicking on airplane mode button.

Here is code snippet for the same.

```
public void enableAirplaneMode(AndroidDriver driver) 
    {
        driver.swipe(350, 10, 350, 700, 1000);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.swipe(350, 10, 350, 700, 1000);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("Airplane mode")));
        String AirplaneMode=driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("Airplane mode")).getText();
        if (AirplaneMode.equals("Off"))
        {
        driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("Airplane mode")).click();
        }

        driver.swipe(350, 800, 350, 10, 1000);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.swipe(350, 800, 350, 10, 1000);
    }
```

Hoping this helps.